# Tweet from dynamic Link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search results page where I have managed to dynamically include a tweet button for every result item.

The problem I have is, when the tweet button is clicked, it only tweets the page title and not the search result item.

Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<font face="arial">
<title>Bible Verses Search</title>
<?php
// db req
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="username";
$db_password="password";
$db_name="dbname";
$db_tb_name="tablename";
$db_tb_atr_name="line";
$db_tb_atr_name2="book";
$db_tb_atr_name3="cap";
$db_tb_atr_name4="verse";

//do search task


mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 

$db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%' OR $db_tb_atr_name2 like '%".$query."%' 
OR $db_tb_atr_name3 like '%".$query."%' OR $db_tb_atr_name4 like '%".$query."%'");

echo "Search Results<ol>";

//bible query new section begins


define ('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define ('USERNAME', 'username');
define ('PASSWORD', 'password');
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'dbname');

$db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to    
MySQL.');

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

$query = "SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<center><a href='page25.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center>";

//mysql_free_result($result);
//mysql_close();

//new bible query section ends




while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
echo "<li>";

echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name2], 0,160)," ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name3], 0,160)," ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name4], 0,160)," ";

echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);

echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-   
url="page25.php?id=$row[id]">Tweet</a>';


echo "</li><hr/>";
}

echo "<center><a href='page25.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center> ";

echo "</ol>";

//mysql_close();
?>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)
[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))    
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

</font>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be using double quotes on the link string rather than single. As you have it now, `$row[id]` is _not_ interpolated correctly in the single quotes. Reverse them to use double on the outer string and single on the `data-url=` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data-text` and put the search result in it like this

```
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-   
url="page25.php?id=' . $row[id] . '" data-text="' . substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160). '">Tweet</a>';
```

You can put other value in `data-text` for example `data-text="value you want here"`

if you want to put page link and title you can do it like this

```
echo "<a href='twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='page25.php?id=$data_fetch[id]' 
    data-text='page25.php?id=$data_fetch[id]\n$data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name]'>Tweet</a>";
```

Comment: Hi manoj, your answer was right if I wanted the "result item" tweeted. What I actually meant was a link to the verse display page using the dynamic id. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Hey I don't get it what you want, you can put in `data-text` what you what for example `data-text="value you want here"`, if you want to put link you can do like this `echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-   
url="page25.php?id=' . $row[id] . '" data-text="page25.php?id=' . $row[id] . '">Tweet</a>';`

Comment: Thanks manoj, this is what I did:                                echo "<a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='page25.php?id=$row[id]' data-text='page25.php?id=$row[id]'>Tweet</a>"; It works, but the only problem now is how to get the page title to display? Thanks.

Comment: Please this superceeds the above comment: echo "<a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='page25.php?id=$row[id]' data-text='page25.php?id=$row[id]'>Tweet</a>"; works, but 2 problems now: 1. it only displays the same link for all elements 2. the page title does not get displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Link is same because `$row` is not changing in while loop use `$data_fetch` instead of `$row` and in `data-text` you can also put page title. I have updated the answer check.

Comment: Thanks manoj, the updated answer works. I will mark it as the solution. However if you have the time, you could also show me how to make the title and link on separate rows.

Comment: Hello again Manoj. I noticed that when I apply the solution above, and have my tweet republished on facebook, it shows a different text value than the verse tweeted, but the link is OK. Can you help? Thanks.